# How to enumerate files in HDFS directory

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

How do I enumerate files in HDFS directory? This is for enumerating files in Apache Spark cluster using Scala.  I see there is sc.textfile() option but that will read the contents as-well. I want to read only file names.

I actually tried the listStatus. But didn't work. Get the below error. 
I am using Azure HDInsight Spark and the blob store folder "testContainer@testhdi.blob.core.windows.net/example/" contains .json files.

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("wasb://testContainer@testhdi.blob.core.windows.net/example/"))
status.foreach(x=> println(x.getPath)

=========
Error:
========
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Filewasb://testContainer@testhdi.blob.core.windows.net/example does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.listStatus(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2076)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:23)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:28)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at <init>(<console>:34)
    at .<init>(<console>:38)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at com.cloudera.livy.repl.scalaRepl.SparkInterpreter$$anonfun$executeLine$1.apply(SparkInterpreter.scala:272)
    at com.cloudera.livy.repl.scalaRepl.SparkInterpreter$$anonfun$executeLine$1.apply(SparkInterpreter.scala:272)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at scala.Console$.withOut(Console.scala:126)
    at com.cloudera.livy.repl.scalaRepl.SparkInterpreter.executeLine(SparkInterpreter.scala:271)
    at com.cloudera.livy.repl.scalaRepl.SparkInterpreter.executeLines(SparkInterpreter.scala:246)
    at com.cloudera.livy.repl.scalaRepl.SparkInterpreter.execute(SparkInterpreter.scala:104)
    at com.cloudera.livy.repl.Session.com$cloudera$livy$repl$Session$$executeCode(Session.scala:98)
    at com.cloudera.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$3.apply(Session.scala:73)
    at com.cloudera.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$3.apply(Session.scala:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the hdfs API documentation, try something and post what you have tried !

Comment: I dont understand why you have tried spark api. where as you have to look at hdfs api and scala syntax to do that. As @eliasah suggested please do some ground work(read the api basics) before come and ask in SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because it is actually looking in your the default storage container rather than the testContainer, and thus not finding the example folder.  You can see this by changing the path to wasb://testContainer@testhdi.blob.core.windows.net/ and it will list files from a different container.

I don't know why this is, but I discovered you can fix it by passing the path to the FileSystem.get call like this:

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("wasb://testContainer@testhdi.blob.core.windows.net/example/"), new Configuration())
val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("wasb://testContainer@testhdi.blob.core.windows.net/example/"))
status.foreach(x=> println(x.getPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

[see FileSystem class](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html)

> abstract FileStatus[] listStatus(Path f)
>
> List the statuses of the files/directories in the given path if the
>   path is a directory.

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val status = fs.listStatus(new Path(HDFS_PATH))
status.foreach(x=> println(x.getPath)
```

Note : HDFS api you can access from any language like java or scala below is java example as well

```
/**
     * Method listFileStats.
     * 
     * @param destination
     * @param fs
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void listFileStats(final String destination, final FileSystem fs) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        final FileStatus[] statuss = fs.listStatus(new Path(destination));
        for (final FileStatus status : statuss) {
            LOG.info("--  status {}    ", status.toString());
            LOG.info("Human readable size {} of file ", FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(status.getLen())); //import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: listFileStatus doesn't seem to work on Azure HDInsight. Updated the original question with the error details.

Comment: what version of hadoop you are using

Comment: do hadoop fs -ls -R <path> then based on that you modify your path. Obviously... " new Path("wasb://testContainer@testhdi.blob.core.windows.net/example/"))" mentioned above is wrong.

Comment: were you able to resolve the path issue. I think you are giving wrong path

Comment: Yes, hadoop fs -ls -R <path> works. Get the files enumerated. Somehow listFileStatus doesn't seem to recognize this same path.

Comment: I asked earlier which verison of hadoop/hdfs you are using

Comment: print the output of hadoop fs -ls -R

Comment: new Path("wasb://testConta.... was inluded in the path. isnt it wrong??

Comment: were you able to sort out this?