# Number of subdirectories in a directory?

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, redhat

How to find the number of subdirectories in a specified directory in HDFS?

---

When I do `hadoop fs -ls /mydir/`, I get a Java heap space error, since the directory is too big, but what I am interested in is the number of subdirectories in that directory. I tried:

```
gsamaras@gwta3000 ~]$ hadoop fs -find /mydir/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -print| wc -l
find: Unexpected argument: -maxdepth
0
```

I know that the directory is not empty, thus 0 is not correct:

```
[gsamaras@gwta3000 ~]$ hadoop fs -du -s -h /mydir
737.5 G  /mydir
```

Comment: I don't understand how an `ls` command would cause a heap space error. It should just be listing out directories.

Comment: And I think only the path and the expression are valid for the [`-find`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#find) command, that's why you got 0 - You got an error.

Comment: Similar question for files here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342400/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-in-hadoop-hdfs#11345280 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903445/how-to-enumerate-files-in-hdfs-directory?rq=1

Comment: @cricket_007 probably it needs to do some computations inside HDFS, I am not sure, that's why an upvote would be deserved I think, I made you learn something today (kidding)! I have seen both questions, there are more actually, but whatever I have tried from *the command-line* will just not do the trick, I did try (for example just now) with `hadoop fs -ls -R /mydir` and got `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space: failed reallocation of scalar replaced objects`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to use is: 
`hdfs dfs -ls  -R /path/to/mydir/ | grep "^d" | wc -l`

But this will also give you the error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. In order to avoid the error, you need to increase the java heap space and run the same command as:

`export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="$HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS -Xmx5g"` and then

`hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/to/mydir/ | grep "^d" | wc -l` .....#For all sub-directories

OR

`hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/mydir/ | grep "^d" | wc -l` .....#For maxdepth=1