# Find number of directories that start with a number

Tags: linux, unix, hadoop, terminal, filesystems

Following [Number of subdirectories in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856659/number-of-subdirectories-in-a-directory), I am now trying to take into account only the directories that start with a number.

For example, if I do:

```
hadoop fs -ls -R foo_dir | grep "^d" | wc -l
```

for:

> foo_dir/18740802-Parthenon.dat.bz2
>
> foo_dir/98740802-Whitby Abbey.dat.bz2
>
> foo_dir/photos_collect.bz2

I will get 3 as result. How to filter that directory to get 2 (idea: check if the first letter of the item is 1-9)?

Comment: Yes, I have full rights to everything @JefréN.!

Comment: Good question @JefréN., because I did apply your answer in a toy directory I created locally and it worked. Yes, the command is executed from the gateway into a completely different directory! Like `/some_dir/foo_dir`

Comment: Gave explanation.

Comment: Thanks @JefréN., you are *the* bomb, couldn't have done it without you! Cheers! ;)

Comment: Thanks. #egoInflatingRapidly :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
... ls -R foo_dir | grep "/[0-9][^/]*$" -c
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

`/` is the directory separator on linux systems.
`[0-9]` matches any digit.
`[^/]*` matches zero or more characters that are **not** directory separators.
`$` matches the end of a line.

Hence, we match any directory or file that starts with a digit and is the **last** entry in the filepath.

---

**PS:** The `-c` arguement to `grep` causes grep to print the number of matching lines.